# Usage of OrderedOptions in Rails.application.secrets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've been working on a new code base that is using Rails 4.1.1. I have a `secrets.yml` file with a format similar to this:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 12345

  foo: &development_foo
    application_id: 2345
    username: foobar
    password: Password123

test:
  ...
  foo:
    <<: *development_foo
```

`Rails.application.secrets` is an object of class `OrderedOptions`. [According to the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedOptions.html) for `OrderedOptions`, the class exists simply to allow you to access values in key/value pairs like this: `Rails.applications.secrets.secret_key_base`. This way, I can access all of the top-level keys inside of the development group using dot notation.

However, when you try to access `appication_id` using the same dot notation (`Rails.application.secrets.foo.application_id`), you get a `undefined method 'application_id' for #<Hash>` error. This is due to the fact that `foo` is not an instance of `OrderedOptions`, but instead is just a plain `Hash`.

What is the rationale for making only the top-level keys instances of `OrderedOptions`? Why not make all of the keys `OrderedOptions` so that you can use dot notation for everything? I can understand that using dot notation could get ugly if you have a deeply nested value inside of `secrets.yml`, but I was curious as to why this decision might have been made.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting bits from Rails sorce code

from *ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions < Hash*:

```
def method_missing(name, *args)
  name_string = name.to_s
  if name_string.chomp!('=')
    self[name_string] = args.first
  else
    self[name]
  end
end
```

from *Rails::Application*:

```
def secrets #:nodoc:
  @secrets ||= begin
    secrets = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    yaml = config.paths["config/secrets"].first
    if File.exist?(yaml)
      require "erb"
      all_secrets = YAML.load(ERB.new(IO.read(yaml)).result) || {}
      env_secrets = all_secrets[Rails.env]
      secrets.merge!(env_secrets.symbolize_keys) if env_secrets
    end

    # Fallback to config.secret_key_base if secrets.secret_key_base isn't set
    secrets.secret_key_base ||= config.secret_key_base
    # Fallback to config.secret_token if secrets.secret_token isn't set
    secrets.secret_token ||= config.secret_token

    secrets
  end
end
```

As you can see `Rails.application.secrets` is an instance of `ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions`. 
OrderedOptions is a simple hash with method_missing method to look up key values as they are methods.

So in your `secrets.yml` for development env keys are: `secret_key_base` and `foo`, so you can use them (and only them) as a method calls.